# Can you compare objects by address for equality?

Tags: c++

I have a function that compares objects by each attribute to see if they are identical. But I was just wondering, would it be better to compare the object by their address instead of checking if they are exactly same objects?

Comment: If the two objects have the same address, they are the same. Though if two objects have the same attributes, they are not necessarily the same...

Comment: Well, do you want to check that the objects are equal, or whether they are the same object? This is not the same.

Comment: Ah I guess I worded my title wrong, I'm seeking if they are the same object and not different objects with equal value;

Comment: Who are "they"? Two pointers? Two references? A pointer and a value? Two values obviously cannot be "the same object"

Comment: Personally my wording would be that two objects "are the same object" if and only if they have the same address, and "have the same value" or "are equal" if the comparison of attributes returns true. To be really pedantic, I'd have to say "two complete objects", because it's possible for two "different" subobjects to have the same address if the implementation uses the empty base class optimization. And obviously union members can have the same address.

Comment: @SteveJessop Some good points there. Still, to be even more pedantic, I'd say that *two objects* are never the same object, by definition :-)

Comment: "two pointers point to the same object if..." would be a less paradoxical starting point

Comment: @Kos: true, I'm working from common terminology in the subject I first trained in, which is mathematics. We say, "consider two functions `f` and `g`", and it is understood that we don't mean to assert that `f!=g`. We don't have to say "consider a function `f` and a function `g`" in order that they be permitted to be equal. It's slightly sloppy, but it's unambiguous provided that everyone is aware of the convention. The reason I don't want to start from talking about pointers was that as far as the question is concerned, the objects might be identified by pointer, by reference, or by name.

Comment: But if I did start that way I'd carry on like this: for any type T, two pointers of type "cv-qualified pointer to cv-qualified T" refer to the same object if and only if they are equal, and are not null pointers. Maybe special-case when T is void.

Comment: Anyway it's not just programmers and `equals` functions, the English languages also struggles to use the concept of identity and the verb "to be" in a consistent or philosophically satisfying way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Korzybski#.22To_be.22

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should decide whether your classes are meant to support *equivalence* or *identity*. Equivalence is a property typical of *values*, such as numbers. Identity is a property typical of *entities*, such as people.

Equivalence is usually determined by comparing the data members of a class; comparing addresses is a reasonable way to check for identity.

Comment: Though identity entails equivalence, is often quicker to test (often very much so) and comparing something with itself comes up often enough, that when you do want to support equivalence it can be worth testing for identity as a short-cut, too.

Comment: However let's not confuse concepts with optimizations

Comment: I think it's worth it in this case, because in itself that it works shows the relationship between the two concepts: An object must always be equivalent to itself, if it isn't, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Actually, while reference comparison makes sense in languages as Java or C# where instances of user defined classes are always heap allocated, I don't find it as reasonable for C++ value classes, which are usually allocated directly.

Answer (score 37):

EDIT: Beware: you cannot pass values (objects) to your function if you want it to work correctly. You need to pass either (probably const) references or pointers.

If you just want to know whether both references or pointers point to the same object (not identical objects, but the same), comparing the addresses is the right thing to do, indeed:

```
bool AreEqual(const Class& a, const Class& b)
{
  return &a == &b;
}
```

---

Note that the `&` operator may be overloaded for the `Class` class above. Since C++11 the function template `std::addressof` is available to cope with that fact:

```
#include <memory> //std::addressof
bool AreEqual(const Class& a, const Class& b)
{
  return std::addressof(a) == std::addressof(b);
}
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore the wording took a wrong turn near "both [objects]" if we want to be strict :)

Comment: @Kos: If anybody knows how to express that correctly in English, I will gladly update my answer :)

Comment: @Gorpik how about "If you want to know whether two given pointers or references point to the same object"?

Comment: @nyarlathotep: I had not considered that because I had read *objects* in the question, but this leads me into something else. I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that you make a proper distinction between same and equal.

Two pointers pointing to the same address means that they point to the same object. So yes: same address means same object and therefore equal (although equality makes sense only if we talk about more than 1 object).

Same attributes don't necessarily mean the same object. E.g. you can have two users with the same name "John Doe". The objects representing them would still be different objects, so they can't be used interchangeably. However, if you have a Point class, then two different instances of `{1, 2}` really represent the same thing and can be used interchangeably.

There is a larger issue of difference between [value objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject) and [reference objects or entities](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ReferenceObject), so I suggest to look it up.

E.g. if you have a Point class, then two different instances of `{1, 2}` really represent the same thing, unlike the User example before.

Answer (score 2):

If you have objects for which comparison is time consuming, comparing the pointers could be used as a fast way to determine object equivalence (i.e., if the pointers are equal, objects are equivalent, otherwise they may still be equivalent)