# Compare pointer with reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am refactoring a legacy code. I have to compare a pointer with reference for equality (To check whether both objects are equal). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403659/can-you-compare-objects-by-address-for-equality) in SO does it by comparing the address. if I do the same for pointer and reference as below, would there be any issues (any exceptional cases?). So far in my testing, it's working properly. Please advice

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class MemberData
{
    //Huge class with many data members
};

int main()
{
    MemberData  x ;
    const MemberData& y = x;
    MemberData *ptr= &x;


    if(std::addressof(*ptr)==std::addressof(y))
    {
            std::cout << "Both are equal" << "\n";  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say _to check whether both objects are equal_ do you mean to check whether they are _equal_, or to check whether they are the _exact same object_

Comment: @Tas check exact same object. Please check my comments for eerorika

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::addressof(*ptr)` seems redundant. If you have a pointer to the object, and you need a pointer to the object, then why indirect through the pointer and then get the pointer to object that was being pointed at? `ptr == std::addressof(y)` should work just as fine. As long as you want to compare equality of the address...

> (To check whether both objects are equal)

Comparing equality of addresses is comparing identity, i.e. whether they are the same object. To compare equality of objects, you'd generally compare their value. For example, following variables are not the same object and thus do not have the same address, but they are equal in value (assuming sane copy constructor):

```
MemberData x;
MemberData y = x;
```

Comment: Better I explain the big picture. one vector container has list of members and the member I compare against is a const &memberdata  inside a function which is from the vector container.  Since it's const& reference along all the way no need to compare their value and it's expensive because it's huge. So Identity comparison is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide will always print the "Both are equal" because what you did is checking the address of x and the address of an alias of x, which is of course the same. The real question is do you just wanna check the equality of address instead of their inner members, i.e. two objects with different address but the same class with the same values.